# How does DirectShow manage default filters?

Tags: directshow

When I render a media file with DirectShow (allowing DirectShow to build the graph automatically) I see that DirectShow has a set of default filters it uses. I also observed that installing 3rd party filters may change some default filters (usually 3rd parties set their own filters as default). 
I was wondering how the default filters are managed (registry?) and how can I change them? How to cause a certain filter to be used by default?

Thanks,
Aliza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such exactly thing as "default" filters in DirectShow. There is a merit system instead: each filter registration is provided with a merit for a filter. When fitler graph renders pins and streams, it starts with trying filters with higher merits.

See more at MSDN:

- [Intelligent Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Guidelines for Registering Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388793%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: what if two filters have the same merit. which is chosen?

Comment: It's up to Filter Mapper, a DirectShow component to decide. The merit system has been known as a place for "merit wars" where developers of third party components are registering their filters under unreasonably high merits to take over rendering. As a developer of filters, you should rather stick to MS guidelines as for merits.

Comment: As a developer using available filters, the best strategy is to (a) build filter graph manually adding filters explicitly when it comes to critical parts and popular formats where you don't want to rely on Intelligent Connect proving a "default" filter for you (b) leave rendering to DirectShow default otherwise (c) blacklist filters/CLSIDs known to be a problem.